# How can I modify the content of an HTML page after redirecting from a form using only JavaScript/HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm learning HTML and I'm trying to do some very basic stuffs. I have my main page under index.html, a registration form under registration.html, and a script under script.js.

Index.html has the following button: `<BUTTON id="login" onclick="register()">login/registration</BUTTON>`

```
function register()
{
    if (!loggedIn)
        document.location.href = "registration.html";
    else
    {
        // Page not created yet
        //document.location.href = "aacount.html";
        console.log("redirecting to account page");
    }
```

In script.js, at the top, I have `let loggedIn = false;`.

The form's submission button looks like this: `<button type="submit" class="submit" onclick="submit()"><b>Submit</b></button>`

```
function submit(){loggedIn = true;}
```

Now on my main page, I have the login button. I would like it to change to an Account button so I made this:

```
function checkLog()
{
    if (loggedIn == true)
        document.getElementById("login").textContent = "Account";
    else
        document.getElementById("login").textContent = "Login/Registration";
}
```

I want my form, which has the header `form class="registration_form" action="index.html" method="post" id="form"` to redirect to the main page once you click submit. Since you're now logged in, I want the `login/registration` to swap to an `account` button. I don't have any backend because I haven't learned how yet. I just want to modify `index.html` once it loads back in by using the `checkLog()` function. Is there a way to do this using only HTML/JavaScript? I have seen a couple solutions using PHP, but I will only jump into it next week once I have more free time. Until then, can I make it work this way?

Just to be sure, I have tried adding `onload="checkLog()"` to both the entire body text and the login button to no avail. I've also found out that adding `onclick="checkLog()"` on the submit button in the form doesn't do anything since it executes before the action of changing web pages occur. I basically want a `onclick=""` that occurs after the action.

Comment: In the absence of a back-end, you will have to store state on the client side. Take a look at [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) (cookies could be another option). Obligatory warning since the code deals with registration and authentication: enforcing any kind of security on the client-side is utterly pointless.

Comment: Security is fine. This is more of an exercise to learn the basics. I don't really care about info retention right now, I was going to learn that tomorrow. This is more about webpage modifications after submitting a form.

Comment: The client does not maintain state across redirects. From the perspective of the browser, there's no such thing as "after submitting a form". It's just a fresh page load with a blank state. That's why you need to maintain state somewhere, e.g. in `localStorage`.

Comment: @BloodLord What @RobbyCornelissen suggests is not about data persistence, but rather about state management. That is, you need to determine whether user is `loggedIn`, and render the relevant information accordingly. Typically, such a state is driven from a server somewhere. Robby's suggestion is you can fake it by updating `loggedIn` state in `localStorage`. Unfortunately, state management, authentication, and their adjacent features aren't really part of "learning the basics".

Answer (score 2):

As a lot suggested in the comments, since there is no server-side to your project yet you're trying to check if the user is logged in to your website, your best bet is either cookies or `LocalStorage`. In this answer I will take the `LocalStorage` approach.

```
    function register()
{
    if (localStorage.getItem("userAuthentication") === null)
        storage.setItem("userAuthentication", "userAuthentication");
        document.getElementById("login").textContent = "Login/Registration";
    else {
        // User is logged in
        // Since the user must have localStorage set up
        console.log("redirecting to account page");
        document.getElementById("login").textContent = "Account";
    }
}
```

The `getItem` attribute returns `null` if the item does not exist; meaning the item hasn't been set yet. if so, we need to set `LocalStorage`, and change the login button text to "Login/Registration". Else, the `localStorage` has to be set, meaning we can can change the login button text to "Account".